# Copy w/ rename a file into res/xml folder

Tags: android, gradle

I would like a gradle task to copy a file into the res/xml folder and name it overrides.xml.  I have a number of possible overrides files to choose from so I would like to specify the filename at build time.

ie in res/xml (I can always store these in another folder as well):

overrides1.xml
overrides2.xml
overrides3.xml

I would like to build and say copy res/xml/overrides1.xml to /res/xml/overrides.xml

A number of questions:

1. Is this possible?  Imagine so as its a simple copy command.
2. Where/how should I do this?  Write a custom task?  Extend a task?
3. How to attach this to the build lifecycle in the right place.
4. Is there already a "copy resources" task that I can somehow tie into?

Comment: based on what? there is no need for that if it is flavor/build type based ... just instead `main/res/xml` put em to `release/res/xml`(build type) or `flavor/res/xml`(flavor)  or `flavorDebug/res/xml`(both) or `etc...` http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Sourcesets-and-Dependencies

Comment: I cannot get a flavor build to work.  I am publishing an aar.  If I set it to publish all flavors, I cannot specify to pull in a particular flavor in my app project without running into compile time problems.  So tried flavors, could not get it to work.  Question still stands.

Comment: hmmm looks like everything is in the doc: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Library-Publication